# Javafx 2.0 : How to change the size of the radio-buttons circle with CSS?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, fxml, scenebuilder

I try to change the radio-buttons size in my app build with FXML and CSS.
I use the sceneBuilder.

Thanks for your help !

Here is my actual CSS code for the radio-buttons :

```
.radio-button .radio{
-fx-border-width     : 1px   ;
-fx-border-color     : #000  ;
-fx-background-color : white ;
-fx-background-image : null  ;
-fx-border-radius    : 15px  ;
-fx-height           : 15px  ; /* Not working */
height               : 5px   ; /* Not working */
}
.radio-button .radio:selected{
-fx-background-color : white ;
-fx-background-image : null  ;
}
.radio-button -radio:armed{
-fx-background-color : white ;
-fx-background-image : null  ;
}
.radio-button -radio:determinate{
-fx-background-color : white ;
-fx-background-image : null  ;
}
.radio-button -radio:indeterminate{
-fx-background-color : white ;
-fx-background-image : null  ;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-fx-padding: 10px;`

A single padding value means that all padding are the same, if a set of four padding values is specified, they are used for the top, right, bottom, and left edges of the region.

from the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

Example:

CssTest.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CssTest extends Application 
{
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        RadioButton radio = new RadioButton("radio-text");
        root.setCenter(radio);
        root.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/radio.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

radio.css

```
.radio-button .radio {
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
    -fx-border-color: #000;
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-background-image: null;
    -fx-border-radius: 15px;
    -fx-padding: 4px;
}
.radio-button .radio:selected {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-background-image: null;
}
.radio-button -radio:armed {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-background-image: null;
}
.radio-button -radio:determinate {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-background-image: null;
}
.radio-button -radio:indeterminate {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-background-image: null;
}
.radio-button .dot {
    -fx-background-radius: 15px;
    -fx-padding: 8px;
}
```

result

[image: Styled JavaFX RadioButton]

For more inspirational JavaFX CSS themes, check **win7glass.css** from [GreggSetzer/JavaFX-CSS-Themes](https://github.com/GreggSetzer/JavaFX-CSS-Themes)

Comment: thanks but it don't help me to change the size of the checkbox and the radio-buttons

Comment: Thank you with all my heart !