# Change checkbox size in JavaFX8

Tags: checkbox, javafx-8, styling

is there a way to change the size of a checkbox in JavaFx 8? The default size is pretty big and I found no way to change it, not with css nor by using the API of the checkbox control itself.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change the box's size of the CheckBox,you can use:

```
.check-box > .box {
    -fx-padding: 10px;
}
```

and you also want to change the check mark,you can use:

```
.check-box > .box > .mark {
    -fx-padding: 10px;
}
```

with the above css you can get a preview

[image]

All the javafx's built-in css selectors are in com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css of jfxrt.jar

Answer (score 0):

Hey you could use the padding to achieve that. 
Here is an example with radiobuttons.

[Javafx 2.0 : How to change the size of the radio-buttons circle with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038179/javafx-2-0-how-to-change-the-size-of-the-radio-buttons-circle-with-css)

Should be the same in JavaFX 8 since its done with css

Answer (score 0):

The CheckBox class provides several methods to set the size. `.setPrefSize()` takes two doubles that set the preferred width and height.

```
        CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
        box.setPrefSize(prefWidth, prefHeight);
```